# Change Password script on Liferay Portal

Tags: passwords, liferay

I have created a dashboard using Liferay Portal and I also have a seperate User management Server (OpenLDAP).

My requirement is when user changes the password through
`Liferay portal` → `My Account` → `Password` → `Save`, it should automatically be updates in my LDAP server.

For that I have to incorporate some changes in password script of Liferay portal.

Where can i find the password script? or lets say, which script is called when user changes the password and clicks save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hook to update the password. Since ultimately liferay will store the password in the database through a method in `UserServiceImpl` and `UserLocalServiceImpl` and the database table `User_` is going to be updated which is represented by the model `User`.

So can use any of the following approaches:

1. Use a [Wrapper hook](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-portal-servi-4). Write your custom code in your `*UserServiceWrapper` class's `updateUser` method.
2. Or use a [Model Listener hook](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-Model+Listeners). Create a `UserListener` and use the method `onAfterUpdate` and/or `onAfterCreate` to write your custom code.

Have you also considered using the `Portal Settings` LDAP export option?
`Portal Settings` → `Authentication` → `LDAP` → `Import / Export`, more information in [Liferay User-guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/ldap)

Comment: Hi Prakash,Thank you  very much for your reply. I have already tried option Portal Settings ------> Authentication------>LDAP-----> import/export. But i think export doesn't update the change in LDAP server.

Answer (score 2):

In `../deploy/ROOT.war/html/portal` folder there is `update_password.jsp` which is responsible for presenting the UI.

If you check this JSP page, the action that gets called is `/portal/update_password`

If you check `struts-config.xml` file present in `../deploy/ROOT.war/WEB-INF` folder, you will get the corresponding action which gets invoked. Below is the code,

```
<action path="/portal/update_password" type="com.liferay.portal.action.UpdatePasswordAction">
   <forward name="portal.update_password" path="portal.update_password" />
</action>
```

If you check the class `UpdatePasswordAction` present in `com.liferay.portal.action` package then the relevant code which changes the password of the User is below,

```
protected void updatePassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ThemeDisplay themeDisplay, Ticket ticket)
    throws Exception
  {
   ....
   UserLocalServiceUtil.updatePassword(
      userId, password1, password2, passwordReset);
  ..
  }
```

Comment: Hi vikas, I reached to the struts-Config.xml but not able to locate UpdatePasswordAction class. Can you please tel me how to access the UpdatePasswordAction class

Comment: @Rupesh I think you can go with the hook approach instead of modifying classes in EXT. Hooks are hot-deployable and less intrusive.